# Simpson's Definition of Parameters and Definability

Tags: logic, reverse-math

Simpson makes his definition of parameters and definability in Definition I.2.3 of his book *Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic* (can be found [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa/chapter1.pdf)).

On page 5 he says that: "Note that an $L_2$-structure $M$ satisfies the comprehension scheme
if and only if $\mathcal{S}_M$ contains all subsets of $|M|$ which are definable over $M$ allowing parameters from $|M|∪\mathcal{S}_M$".

Based on his definition of the comprehension scheme, why do we need to allow parameters from $|M|\cup\mathcal{S}_M$ for the above statement to hold?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comprehension scheme (as usually defined, which agrees with Simpson's definition) allows for formulas with arbitrary numbers of parameters. That is, each axiom in the scheme may have additional free variables. This is why Simpson mentions universal closures in Definition 1.2.4. He discusses this in the first paragraph of page 5.

Therefore, the comprehension scheme corresponds to definability with parameters.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I see that basically he is defining the comprehension scheme as: For any formula $\varphi$ in the language of $L_2$ with free variables $\overline{m}=m_1,…,m_j$ and $\overline{X}=X_1,…,X_k$ we have

$∀\overline{m}\forall\overline{X}∃Z∀n(n∈Z↔φ(n))$. I guess my confusion was really as to why he says "parameters from $|M|\cup\mathcal{S}_M$" rather than just simply "parameters" as he refers to it on page 5 (as you pointed out). I suppose I'm reading into it too much...

Comment: I left out: Provided $Z$ does not appear in $\varphi$, in defining the comprehension scheme above.

Comment: The word "parameter" can mean two things. In the context of the comprehension scheme, which is defined without reference to any model, we talk about "parameters" but they are really just universally quantified free variables in $\phi$. In the context of a particular model, we move to an extended language where there is a constant for each element of $|M| \cup \mathcal{S}_M$. Then we do not need free variables (see I.2.3, p.3). This is covered very quickly in the text because, I think, Simpson views it as background material from logic, and he just wants to set his terminology and move forward.